# If $z+\frac{1}{z}=2\cos\theta,$ where $z\in\Bbb C$, show that $\left|\frac{z^{2 n}-1}{z^{2n}+1}\right|=|\tan n\theta|$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, solution-verification

If $z+\frac{1}{z}=2 \cos \theta,$ where $z$ is a complex number, show that
$$
\left|\frac{z^{2 n}-1}{z^{2 n}+1}\right|=|\tan n \theta|
$$

**My Approach:**

$$
\begin{array}{l}|\sin \theta|=\left|\sqrt{1-\cos ^{2} \theta}\right| \\ =\left|\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{z^{2}+1}{2z}\right)^{2}}\right| \\ =\left|\sqrt{\frac{4 z^{2}-z^{4}-2 z^{2}-1}{4 z^{2}}} \right|\\ =\left|\sqrt{\frac{-\left(z^{4}-2 z^{2}+1\right)}{4 z^{2}}}\right|=\left|\sqrt{\frac{\left(z^{2}-1\right)^{2}}{4 z^{2}}}\right| \\ =|\frac{z^{2}-1}{2 z}|\end{array}
$$

So $|\tan \theta|=\left|\frac{z^{2}-1}{z^{2}+1}\right|$ ( proven when $n = 1$)

*Is there any way to prove directly by taking $n$?*

Comment: add missing absolute values

Comment: I think you need restriction on $\theta$

Comment: I think you are trying to apply induction here but I don't think that is going to be a trivial .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$z+\frac 1z=2\cos \theta\Rightarrow z^2-2\cos\theta z+1=0$$
Solve this quadratic to obtain 
$$z=cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta$$
Or,
$$z=e^{i\theta},e^{-i\theta}$$
Now,
$$\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^{2n}+1}=\frac{z^n-1/z^n}{z^n+1/z^n}$$
In either of the above cases(for $z$), we have,
$$z^n+1/z^n=e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}=2\cos n\theta$$
But depending on the value of $z$ we have
$$z^n-1/z^n=\pm \left(e^{in\theta}-e^{-in\theta}\right)=\pm 2\sin n\theta$$
We now have
$$\left |\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z^{2n}+1}\right |=\left|\frac{\pm 2\sin n\theta}{2\cos n\theta}\right|=|\tan n\theta|$$
Hence proved.

Comment: got it! I want to know ,Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: @RANCHO Your approach is correct, but that proves the statement only for $n=1$. For other values of $n$ you can use induction when $n$ is a natural number. Or you can also use what I have described.

Comment: okay! so can i conclude ,as LHS supports for n =1 ,then for all n it is true.

Comment: @RANCHO **NO**. Induction doesn't work like that that. For example, take the quadratic $f(n)=n^2+n+41$. On calculation for a few values, it seems that it generates primes for all $n$, but that's not true. Only until $n=40$ it holds, and at $40$, the output is $41^2$. Your method(if true for $n=1$ then true for all) gives the wrong conclusion.

Comment: okay i understood

Answer (score 1):

You could express the equation directly as a quadratic:

$z^2 - 2 z \cos \theta + 1 = 0$

and use the quadratic formula, for further insight.

Comment: u mean finding the z value and putting into the LHS?

Comment: Get what $z$ is in terms of $\cos \theta$ and see what happens. It's an approach you may want to try, as it's a technique which should be in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method avoids solving quadratic equation

Take $|z|=r>0$ and let $z=re^{i\phi}=r(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$ for some $\phi \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

**$$  z+\frac{1}{z} =re^{i\phi}+\frac{1}{re^{i\phi}}=  re^{i\phi}+\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\phi}= r(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)+\frac{1}{r}(\cos \phi - i \sin \phi)$$** **$$=\left( r\cos \phi +\frac{1}{r}   \cos \phi  \right)+  
i\left(  r\sin \phi-\frac{1}{r}\sin \phi \right)=2\cos \theta $$**
Then observe $Re\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)=2\cos \theta$ and $Im \left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)=0 \implies r\sin \phi-\frac{1}{r}\sin \phi =0$

From this you can show that $$|z|=1\text{ and }(\cos \phi =\cos \theta \implies \phi\equiv \theta \text{ or } -\theta \mod 2\pi)\\ \therefore z=e^{i\phi}=e^{i\theta} \text{ or } e^{-i\theta} $$.

Then you have got the result

Comment: how are u coming to this (rsinϕ−1/rsinϕ)=0

Comment: What is the imaginary part of $z+\frac{1}{z}$? And observe it is  equal to 0

Comment: @RANCHO is it ok ?

Comment: it is coming  as sin2ϕ = 0

Comment: Edited the answer for you now have the look .@RANCHO

Comment: yes.It is cleared now

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer then ? @RANCHO

Comment: @Noob mathematician simply getting $\cos \phi=\cos\theta$ doesn't finish the problem. See my answer- more than half of it focuses on finishing the problem. Also, your method *does* involve the usage of the quadratic formula - proving $r=1$ for $r-1/r=0$ ;)

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar but this solving this quadratic equation much much less scarier than solving $z^2-2\cos\theta z+1=0$.

Comment: @Noob mathematician "Scarier"? Why so?

Comment: $z^2-2\cos\theta z+1=0$ how will you solve this?

Comment: simply by quadratic formula i.e z = (-(-2cosθ) +/- (4cos^2θ-4)^1/2)/2*1 this will lead to cosθ±isinθ.

Comment: How will it lead you ? I think you have got the answer why it is scary .

Comment: no it is not at all scary. by solving z value from quadratic eq and then putting it into the LHS seems easier near me!...It is just using 1-cos^2x = sin^2x

Comment: Yeah that sounds great !